# Recursively create a Spark filter with multiple predicates in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe containing a bunch of values

```
val df = List(
  (2017, 1, 1234),
  (2017, 2, 1234),
  (2017, 3, 1234),
  (2017, 4, 1234),
  (2018, 1, 12345),
  (2018, 2, 12346),
  (2018, 3, 12347),
  (2018, 4, 12348)
).toDF("year", "month", "employeeCount")
```

> df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [year: int, month: int, employeeCount: int]

I want to filter that dataframe by a list of (year, month) pairs:

```
val filterValues = List((2018, 1), (2018, 2))
```

I can easily cheat and write the code that achieves it:

```
df.filter(
  (col("year") === 2018 && col("month") === 1) || 
  (col("year") === 2018 && col("month") === 2)
).show
```

but of course that's not satisfactory because `filterValues` could change, and I want to base it on whatever is in that list.

Is it possible to dynamically build my `filter_expression` and then pass it to `df.filter(filter_expression)`? I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876298/recursively-create-a-spark-filter-with-multiple-predicates-in-scala#comment88758259_50876433):

> imagine someone calling this from the command-line with something like --filterColumns "year,month" --filterValues "2018|1,2018|2"

```
val filterValues = "2018|1,2018|2"
val filterColumns = "year,month"
```

you can get a list of columns

```
val colnames = filterColumns.split(',')
```

Convert data to a local `Dataset` (add `schema` when needed):

```
val filter = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|")
  .csv(filterValues.split(',').toSeq.toDS)
  .toDF(colnames: _*)
```

and semi join:

```
df.join(filter, colnames, "left_semi").show
// +----+-----+-------------+             
// |year|month|employeeCount|
// +----+-----+-------------+
// |2018|    1|        12345|
// |2018|    2|        12346|
// +----+-----+-------------+
```

Expression like this one should work as well:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val pred = filterValues
  .split(",")
  .map(x => colnames.zip(x.split('|'))
                    .map { case (c, v) => col(c) === v }
                    .reduce(_ && _))
  .reduce(_ || _)

df.where(pred).show
// +----+-----+-------------+
// |year|month|employeeCount|
// +----+-----+-------------+
// |2018|    1|        12345|
// |2018|    2|        12346|
// +----+-----+-------------+
```

but will require more work if some type casting is required.

Comment: that works great, thank you. Still interested in some of the other posited answers as they solve it in different ways, but thank you very much.

Comment: actually I really really like the second answer you gave. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do that using a `udf` function as

```
val filterValues = List((2018, 1), (2018, 2))

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def filterUdf = udf((year:Int, month:Int) => filterValues.exists(x => x._1 == year && x._2 == month))

df.filter(filterUdf(col("year"), col("month"))).show(false)
```

**Updated**

You commented as

> > I mean that the list of columns to filter on (and the corresponding list of respective values) would be supplied from elsewhere at runtime.

for that you will have list of column names provided too, so the solution would be something like below

```
val filterValues = List((2018, 1), (2018, 2))
val filterColumns = List("year", "month")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def filterUdf = udf((unknown: Seq[Int]) => filterValues.exists(x => !x.productIterator.toList.zip(unknown).map(y => y._1 == y._2).contains(false)))

df.filter(filterUdf(array(filterColumns.map(col): _*))).show(false)
```

Comment: If I wanted to make it even harder by saying "the list of columns that I want to filter on is also unknown, and there can be an arbitrary number of them", how might I do that?

Comment: how can it be possible that the column names are unknown and still you want to filter? On what base do you want to filter, you have to know that at least ;)

Comment: sorry, didn't explain that very well :) I mean that the list of columns to filter on (and the corresponding list of respective values) would be supplied from elsewhere at runtime.

Comment: you mean to say that like you have filterValues you will have list of column names to be used? is that correct?

Comment: imagine someone calling this from the command-line with something like `--filterColumns "year,month" --filterValues "2018|1,2018|2"`

Comment: Please see my updates @jamiet :) I hope I answered your queries well

Comment: Ah unfortunately that won't work because the number of columns that can be filtered upon is also arbitrary. In your example above I think I'm right in saying that `filterColumns` must have at least two columns and only those first two columns will be filtered upon.

Comment: @jamiet, I have updated my answer :) please have a look now

Comment: Rajesh, thanks for persevering. I see what you're trying to do but that last effort returns `not found: value array`. I'm clueless as to why I'm afraid.

Comment: I thought you had `filterValues` as tuples. . Anyway you have already got the answer right?

Comment: I do have the right answer, yes. Nothing wrong with evaluating alternatives though. This thread had been a really good learning experience for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can build up your filter_expression like this :

```
val df = List(
  (2017, 1, 1234),
  (2017, 2, 1234),
  (2017, 3, 1234),
  (2017, 4, 1234),
  (2018, 1, 12345),
  (2018, 2, 12346),
  (2018, 3, 12347),
  (2018, 4, 12348)
).toDF("year", "month", "employeeCount")

val filterValues = List((2018, 1), (2018, 2))

val filter_expession = filterValues
  .map{case (y,m) => col("year") === y and col("month") === m}
  .reduce(_ || _)

df
  .filter(filter_expession)
  .show()

+----+-----+-------------+
|year|month|employeeCount|
+----+-----+-------------+
|2018|    1|        12345|
|2018|    2|        12346|
+----+-----+-------------+
```